# Mots comme « toutafé »

Tags: écriture, internet

Je sais l'origine de « toutafé » et son emploi de nos jours. Quels autres locutions comme « tout à fait » peuvent être également mal écrites par plaisanterie ?

Comment: Il y en a énormément. Beaucoup par *plaisanterie* mais également à cause du "language sms" (limitation par charactère du prix des sms) puis plus tard par la facilité d'écriture en une sorte de phonétique A peu près tout les mots peuvent être mal écris. Vous pourrez évidement trouver des mots/locutions qui reviennent souvent, comme *toutafé* pour *tout à fait*, mais même eux pourront être sujet à variation selon les personnes

Comment: Pour discuter parfois par plaisanterie avec des amis de cette façon, *oui* devient vite *ui*, *c'est* devient *c* et ce n'est que le début. *cpabo* par exemple est une possibilité pour *c'est pas beau*. Pour des locutions particulières cependant, je n'ai pas d'idée de suite. Dans le doute, si vous devez croiser un mot *étrange*, je vous proposerais de le prononcer pour voir s'il revient à une synthétisation d'un / locution existante

Comment: Je ne connais pas _toutafé_ mais au Québec on a le fameux _de kessé/kossé/dkc_  (de quoi s'agit-il/qu'est-ce que) voire _diousse kessé_ (où est-ce), mais je ne sais pas si c'est par plaisanterie hahaha, c'est un truc phonétique très oralisant qui ressemble surtout à une interjection pour la surprise ou l'incompréhension.

Comment: Toutafé, késako?

Comment: @petitrien Selon le commentaire qui précède, ce serait, chronologiquement, une orthographe grippe-sou pour « tout à fait » puis une orthographe dans le vent (pour le même terme).

Comment: @LPH. Comme on dit à Istanbul, Mersi!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut trouver *tout ça* orthographié en *toussa* sur le ton de la plaisanterie, en particulier dans des conversations ou commentaires sur le web. La nuance est alors que *toussa* est utilisé pour abréger ce qui pourrait être une longue énumération d'exemples connus, de clichés ou d'idées préconçues, et qu'on fait confiance à interlocuteur pour comprendre quels autres éléments pourraient être ajoutés.

Par son usage, on peut penser à une variante plus littéraire: l'emprunt à l'italien *tutti quanti*.

Ex:

> Tu as allé à Paris ? Tu as visité quoi ?
>
> Les classiques: tour Eiffel, Champs Elysées, toussa.

ou

> Tu fais quelque chose de spécial pour Noël ?
>
> Non, comme d'hab': dîner chez nous, famille, les parents, cadeaux, toussa.

ou

> Il adore les voitures de luxe, Porsche, Ferrari, toussa.

Comment: On a aussi *kessessé* pour *qu'est-ce que c'est*